# Showing my printed lines in Frame

Tags: java, jframe, jtextarea

I am writing a monopoly game. In game at some points I print "your balance is 1500" or "you diced 12" kind of things. I want to transfer this printed things into my frame with using textarea. I created text area I can see it in my application. But how am I going to see my console in that text area? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Monopoly {
    public Monopoly() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Monopoly");
        Game g = new Game();
        Board b = new Board(g);
        frame.setSize(1368, 750);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(b);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(700, 0, 6, 200);
        b.add(textArea);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `textArea` a private instance field in your class and initialize it in your constructor:

```
private JTextArea textArea;

public Monopoly() {
    // ...
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    // ...
}
```

Then, whenever you need to display something, instead of printing to the console via `System.out`, use the JTextArea's `append` method instead.

```
textArea.append("Your balance is 1500\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        textArea.append(text);
      }
    });
  }

  private void redirectSystemStreams() {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
      @Override
      public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
      }

      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
      }

      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
      }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
  }
```

[Source](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html)